# connect `sqlachemy` to the django db

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to connect `sqlalchemy` to the django db? I am running a django test where a test database is created `connection._connections.settings['default']` gives:

```
{'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', 'NAME': 'test_db', 'USER': 'postgres', 'PASSWORD': 'qwertyu', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'PORT': '5432', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'MIGRATE': True, 'MIRROR': None, 'NAME': None}}
```

But if I try to connect to this database using `sqlalchemy`:

```
user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
        password = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
        database_name = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']

        database_url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@localhost:5432/{database_name}'.format(
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database_name=database_name,
        )

        engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=False)
```

a completely new database is created. So any data inserted using `model.bulkcreate()` live is a different database than the one created by `sqlalchemy`.

I would like to be able to use both. I want to use `sqlalchemy` for long time series (1M to 10M rows) where `model.bulkcreate()` is taking very long.

I find it weird that the engine of `connection` is 'django.db.backends.postgresql', while the engine of `sqlalchemy` is `postgresql+psycopg2` or `postgresql`.

Is there a way to connect `connection` with `sqlalchemy`?

thanks

Comment: SQLAlchemy does not create a new database when connecting to a Postgresql server.  You could create a SQLAlchemy script that populates your dattabase outside of Django, but AFAIK Django does not support SQLAlchemy as a database backend or model provider (but I am not up to date wiht Django, so there could be third party tools for this).  Understand that Django engines and SQLAlchemy engines are different things and are not interchangeable.

Comment: found it. https://rodic.fr/blog/sqlalchemy-django/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found `aldjemy` in a blog here. https://rodic.fr/blog/sqlalchemy-django/

all that is needed is this

```
from aldjemy.core import get_engine
engine = get_engine()
df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine)
```